# How to add a control to another form and take it back

Tags: c#, forms, winforms

I use a `WebBrowser` control in my main form. After loading a webpage, I want to allow the user to manipulate the page in another form. So, I add the webBrowser to that form.

```
  FormBrowser form2 = new FormBrowser();
  form2.Browser = webBrowser1;
  form2.ShowDialog();
```

When the `form2` is shown, the `webBrowser1` disappears from main form and is added to the `form2`, because I add it in the form_load event:

```
private void FormBrowser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (browser != null)
    {
        this.Controls.Add(browser);
    }
}
```

Now I want to add it to the main form and place it in its original location, I tried the following code:

```
.....
browser.Browser = webBrowser1;
browser.ShowDialog();
Controls.Add(webBrowser1);
webBrowser1.BringToFront();
```

But it doesn't place it in its original location. Is there any standard way to do such a task? Why does it disappears from the main form? Can I retain it?

Comment: Why does it disappears from the main form? Because you **moved** it on another form.

Answer (score 1):

Set the x and y values of the Location property of the new control.

Comment: yeah, it seems I must keep its location and size and reassign them.